# Changing specific element in array in useState

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to change a specific element in an array, which is stored inside a useState.

My useState looks like this:

```
    const [pollData, setPollData] = useState(
        [
            "",
            ""
        ]
    )
```

I use the map function to map out some input fields, that when onChange fires should put their value into the specific place in the array. Line A is the closest i've gotten, but it crashes the app and i cant for the life of me figure out the correct syntax.

If i uncomment block B, it works as long as i dont include value={pollData[index]}. Which i need for the visual text to function.

```
pollData && pollData.map((entry, index) => {
                    return(
                        <div className="input-group mb-2" key={index}>   
                            <input placeholder={"Option " + index} className="form-control" value={pollData[index]} onChange={(e) => {
                               

             line A             setPollData(pollData => pollData[index] = "test" ) 


                         
             line B             // let newData = pollData
                                // newData[index] = e.target.value
                                // setPollData(newData)
                                console.log(pollData)



                            }}></input>
                            <button tabindex="-1" className="btn btn-outline-danger" onClick={
                                () => handleDelete(index)
                            }>
                                X
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the value at the index and set the state variable again:

```
const handleChange = (index, value) => {
  const data = [...pollData]
  data.splice(index, 1, value) /* or data[index] = value */
  setPollData(data)
}

pollData && pollData.map((entry, index) => {
        return(
          <div className="input-group mb-2" key={index}>   
           <input placeholder={"Option " + index} className="form-control" value={entry} onChange={(e) => handleChange(index, e.target.value)}}></input>
           <button tabindex="-1" className="btn btn-outline-danger" onClick={() => handleDelete(index)}> X </button>
          </div>
      )
 })
```

You shouldn't mutate the state variable directly. If it is an object or an array, make a copy of it, alter the copy as you wish and set the state variable to the altered copy.

Comment: Thanks, apparantly my block B worked fine, the only thing missing was the spread operator around pollData. I tried logging both pollData and [...pollData] but they were the same. How come one works and one dont?

Comment: If you don't copy the array, but use the original array, react doesn't recognize it as a `change` to re-render. Take a look at [this blog](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/manipulating-arrays-and-objects-in-state-with-react). I will also recommend taking a look at `lodash`